# Microsoft.Data.Sqlite - User defined aggregate window functions

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, microsoft.data.sqlite

I want to know if anybody successfully created an user defined aggregate window function for Sqlite by using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite C# package. I am not even sure if this is supported in the current incarnation of the package. Registering aggregate functions works but apparently not for windows defined over partitions. Is this something coming up in a future package version? Sqlite engine supports it...

Answer (score 0):

We haven't yet (as of version 7.0 preview 3) added corresponding API for the native `sqlite3_create_window_function` API. Can you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose) requesting this feature?